# Who is guru laghima?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

I would like to know who Guru Laghima is.

It's often reddit talks about this guy ([here](http://www.reddit.com/r/TheLastAirbender/comments/2f09ro/why_the_airbending_trick_is_the_greatest/) for example), however they never really explain who he is, they just say something about 4000

Comment: http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Laghima

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Avatar Wiki](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Laghima);

> Guru Laghima was an Air Nomad guru and renowned poet who lived at the
>   Northern Air Temple around 3,829 BG. He discovered the secret to
>   weightlessness, which allowed him to unlock the airbending ability of
>   flight. This essentially allowed Laghima to become untethered from the
>   earth and live the last forty years of his life without ever touching
>   the ground.

The joke in the reddit article you've referenced is that the OP has created a long and convoluted story merely to allow him to add a "Guru Laghima" reference at the end.

Reddit editor 'participating' [explains teh funneh](http://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/2ezwhs/who_is_guru_laghima_and_why_have_i_probably_never/)

> He's a character referenced by one of the the antagonists (Zaheer) of
>   the most recent season of Korra. The way Zaheer mentioned Guru Laghima
>   sounded a bit hipsterish himself. It became a running gag in
>   /r/TheLastAirbender (as things are wont to do in that subreddit). So
>   now, anytime Guru Laghima is mentioned, it starts a chain of comments:
>   Guru Laghima. An airbender who lived 4000 years ago. You've probably
>   never heard of him. Put a sock in it. Classic Bolin.

[image]

Comment: What does BG stand for in this context?

Comment: *"To further clarify the often confusing timeline in Avatar: The Last Airbender, this timeline and other articles date events as years before the Air Nomad Genocide (BG) and years after the genocide (AG). 0 AG is the year Fire Lord Sozin used the power from Sozin's Comet to begin the Hundred Year War with the Air Nomad Genocide and serves as an epoch for the dating system."* ; http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/History_of_the_World_of_Avatar